# How to set maximum height and minimum height for quality tracks in exoplayer

Tags: android, exoplayer, exoplayer2.x

In my project i want to set minimum height and maximum height for a video track. Simply means if we select that track the video should play in between these maximum and minimum quality like the AUTO mode. 
Now we can set maximum video size but i couldn't find any solution for setting minimum height.